# Menuitem without menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

Is it possible to display menuitems in a menuitem without grouping it into a menu ?

```
<MenuItem Header="toto">
    <MenuItem Header="Titi"></MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

This sample display the menu item toto, the expander image, but doesn't show the subitem when mouse is over the toto item

Any idea ?

Comment: The XAML you have posted looks perfectly valid to me. When I tested it, the Titi item appears as required, after a small delay. What happens when you try to expand the menu? Do you have any strange styles set on your objects?

Comment: @bobsmith833: Did you actually place that code is some element which is *not* a menu?

Comment: @H.B. - ah, no I didn't! Oops... Note to self: fit brain into place before attempting to answer questions. Looks like OP has found a solution anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution : 
XAML

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MyMenu" MouseEnter="MenuItem_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MenuItem_MouseLeave" Header="toto" >
    <MenuItem Header="titi"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Code behind :

```cs
private void MenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyMenu.IsSubmenuOpen = true;
}

private void MenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyMenu.IsSubmenuOpen = false;
}
```

Using XAML (Thanks HB for advice, 1st edit):

```
<MenuItem.Style>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Style>
```

Can't use IsHighlighted false, because it is still highlighted when mouse is not over it.
2nd edit : seems that there's a bug when a showdialog windows is shown when menu is open. So we need to combine with MouseEnter event to prevent from this bug. (the bug is that the submenu does not open any more after the popup has been shown)

Comment: You could use a style and triggers for that, might be a bit nicer.